# Confused by simple risk problem

Tags: average, percentages

I am having troubles understanding this basic problem and would like to see if anyone could help me out.

I have two boxes: one red, one blue. Depending on what box I pick, I have the potential to make some money. However, most the time the boxes will be empty. Here are the associated %s that I could pick a box with some money in it:

Red Box (In Dollars)
 
20% : 1,600
 
1% : 2,500 
1% : $1,250 
78% : 0

Blue Box (In Dollars) 
 
10% : 1,600 
3% : 2,500 
5% : 1,250
82% : 0

I am trying to calculate the amount each box represents. I tried the weighted average but for some reason it doesn't seem right...

Red Box:

```
(.2*1600)+(.01*2500)+(.01*1250)+(.78*0) = $357.50
```

Blue Box:

```
(.1*1600)+(.03*2500)+(.05*1250)+(.82*0) = $297.50
```

Am I conceptually wrong here or is this right?

Comment: What do you mean by " I am trying to calculate the amount each box represents?" Kindly make it more clear.

Comment: These values are the expected amounts of money for each box. They are calculated right. But the expected value doesn´t  say anything about the risk.